# How do I access ListViewItem?

Tags: wpf, listview, listviewitem

The `Items` collection of a `ListView` contains the actual business objects. How do I obtain the corresponding `ListViewItem` given a business object (`SelectedItem`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really need to, use the `ListView`'s [ItemsContainerGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainergenerator.aspx) property. However, you can often get away with not setting an `ItemContainerStyle` with `Binding`s:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSpecial}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

In the above XAML, the `ListViewItem`s will be selected if the underlying bound object's `IsSpecial` property is `true`. Selecting/deselecting will update the `IsSpecial` property.

Comment: ListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(ListView.SelectedItem)
Got it! Thanks!